# StAX: START_DOCUMENT on empty XML file

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am trying to understand StAX design with regards to [START_DOCUMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.html#START_DOCUMENT) event. The typical while loop is:

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
try {
  XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
  while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
    switch( xmlEvent.getEventType() ) {
    [...]
```

Using this loop there is no way to distinguish in between an empty XML file vs an XML file with simply the xml version. Eg:

```
% test -s empty.xml || echo empty      
empty
% cat start.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The above two files produce exactly the same series of StAX events (one START_DOCUMENT). Is this behavior documented somewhere ? Why would anyone want a START_DOCUMENT event in the case of an empty file ?

Comment: Either file are equally parseable, as the XML declaration is optional. Neither one is well-formed (mostly because well-formed XML must have a root element), but especially from the perspective of a event parser like stax, these are the same thing.

Comment: This qualifies as an anwer. Please post, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either file are equally parseable, as the XML declaration is optional.

Neither one is well-formed (because a well-formed XML must have a root element), but especially from the perspective of a event parser like StAX, these are the same thing.

After the `START_DOCUMENT` event the next `hasNext` call should throw a `XMLStreamException` indicating that the document isn't well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing a file and the file doesn't contain well-formed XML, then the only thing you can be sure of is that an error will be reported. Neither of the two cases you describe (an empty file, and a file containing only an XML declaration) is well-formed, so you can't rely on anything except the error.

Having said that, if I recall correctly there are differences between StAX parsers in the sequence of events they report, even in cases that are well-formed. It's worth testing your code with more than one.

Comment: I did not know there were multiple StAX implementations. In my mind I assumed that `hasNext()` meant `fpeek() did not return EOF`

Comment: There's an implementation that comes with the JDK, and there is Woodstox. Woodstox in my (not very recent) experience is a lot better.